Default value of input 2 is from input 1. Why does the state of input 2 not get its default value from input 1?
I have 2 <input type="text"> elements. What users type in input 1 will be the default value of input 2. The value of input 2 will be used for other tasks. The tasks should run right when the dialog is opened.
My island code:
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Test() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState("");
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState("");
  console.log("value1:", value1)
  console.log("value2:", value2)

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" autoFocus
        value={value1}
        onInput={e => setValue1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input type="text"
        value={value2 || value1}
        onInput={e => setValue2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      Value2: {value2}
    </div>
  );
}

I expect value2 to show right when input 1 has value. However it doesn't. Only when there is a modification on the value of input 2 that value2 is set. Why is it the case? How to fix this?
What I'm actually doing: I have a search bar to search for saved URLs, and if users want to create new data from new URL, they can paste the URL to the search bar, then a modal will show. Inside the modal there will be a form for them to add more metadata. The first field is the URL, which is what they just paste. The other fields are populated automatically, but they can edit manually. Currently they have to make a dumb edit in the URL field to trigger the task.
Note that in Preact, onInput is used instead of onChange.

To be clear, do you want the state value value2 to be populated, or the second input? Without calling setValue2, value2 will never change -- this is how hooks work.

the second input value is already populated, I want to populate the state value as well.

Had to ask, as there's a number of ways in which that may not be the case. The reality is that you shouldn't be doing this, tying two state values together like this is a very fragile anti-pattern. Can you elaborate more on what you're actually trying to achieve?

What I'm actually doing: I have a search bar to search for saved URLs, and if users want to create new data from new URL, they can paste the URL to the search bar, then a modal will show. Inside the modal there will be a form for them to add more metadata. The first field is the URL, which is what they just paste. The other fields are populated automatically, but they can edit manually. Currently they have to make a dumb edit in the URL field to trigger the task.

Why do you need a second state value? Derive the second value as a normal local variable instead.

without making it as a state, how can I capture what users type in input 2? Can you give an example?

There's usually better patterns available, but without a very specific reproduction, here's one way you could do it:
import { useReducer } from 'preact/hooks';

const initialState = { value1: '', value2: '' };
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.input) {
    case 1: return { value1: action.value, value2: action.value };
    case 2: return { ...state, value2: action.value };
    default: throw new Error('Unexpected action');
  }
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={state.value1} onInput={(e) => dispatch({ input: 1, value: e.currentTarget.value })} />
      <input value={state.value2} onInput={(e) => dispatch({ input: 2, value: e.currentTarget.value })} />
      <p>Value1: {state.value1}</p>
      <p>Value2: {state.value2}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

